# How to accomplish 2D convolution using 1D convolution?

Tags: matlab, convolution

Suppose,

```
u = [1 2 1 3 ; 1 2 1 3 ; 1 2 1 3];
v = [2 0 1 ; 2 0 1 ; 2 0 1];
```

I want to achieve

```
w = conv2(u, v);    % [2 4 3 8 1 3 ; 4 8 6 16 2 6 ; 6 12 9 24 3 9 ; 4 8 6 16 2 6 ; 2 4 3 8 1 3]
```

And, suppose, I don't want to use `conv2()`.

Using Matlab, I discovered that,

```
w1 = conv([1 2 1 3], [2 0 1])   % [2 4 3 8 1 3]
w2 = conv([1 2 1 3], [2 0 1])   % [2 4 3 8 1 3]
w3 = conv([1 2 1 3], [2 0 1])   % [2 4 3 8 1 3]
```

So, we get:

```
w123 = [w1 ; w2 ; w3]           % [2 4 3 8 1 3 ; 2 4 3 8 1 3 ; 2 4 3 8 1 3];
```

Using Matlab, I also discovered that,

```
x = [2 ; 2 ; 2]
y = [1 ; 1 ; 1]
z = conv(x, y); % [2 ; 4 ; 6 ; 4 ; 2];

x = [4 ; 4 ; 4]
y = [1 ; 1 ; 1]
z = conv(x, y); % [4 ; 8 ; 12 ; 8 ; 4];

x = [3 ; 3 ; 3]
y = [1 ; 1 ; 1]
z = conv(x, y); % [3 ; 6 ; 9 ; 6 ; 3];

x = [8 ; 8 ; 8]
y = [1 ; 1 ; 1]
z = conv(x, y); % [8 ; 16 ; 24 ; 16 ; 8];

x = [1 ; 1 ; 1]
y = [1 ; 1 ; 1]
z = conv(x, y); % [1 ; 2 ; 3 ; 2 ; 1];

x = [3 ; 3 ; 3]
y = [1 ; 1 ; 1]
z = conv(x, y); % [3 ; 6 ; 9 ; 6 ; 3];
```

Which means, if we perform 1D convolution on each row of `u` with kernel `[2 0 1]`, and then apply 1D convolution on each column with kernel `[1; 1; 1]`, we obtain:

```
2  4  3  8  1  3
4  8  6 16  2  6
6 12  9 24  3  9
4  8  6 16  2  6
2  4  3  8  1  3
```

So, my question is, where does this `[1 ; 1 ; 1]` come from?

And, most importantly, **what would happen if the rows are not same?**

Comment: Your search term for the day is [Separable Convolution Filter](https://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2006/10/04/separable-convolution/).

Comment: @beaker, So, in short: 2d convolution, in general, isn't achievable from 1d conv. unless the kernel is seperable.

Comment: this is correct

Comment: @beaker, post your comment as an answer and I will accept that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason that your 1D convolutions combine to give you the same results as the 2D convolution is that your filter is [separable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separable_filter). Steve Eddins discussed separable convolutions on his MATLAB blog [here](https://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2006/10/04/separable-convolution/).

Your filter is separable because:

```
[1;1;1] * [2,0,1] = 

   2   0   1
   2   0   1
   2   0   1
```

But in general, not all 2D filters are separable and only those that are can be turned into separate 1D convolutions.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose because your matrix `v` is just the same row 3 times. Therefore you can simply use a 2nd convolution with `[1 1 1]` over the columns

Comment: what if they are not same?

Comment: untested I would assume if the rows are just linear combinations of each other then you can use this approach with the appropriate factor for each row.